Compilation error when trying to set LED pin dynamically via class constructor
I'm trying to create a class that uses FastLED where the LED pin can be set dynamically. However, I'm getting a compilation error when I try to call FastLED.addLeds with a member variable pin.
// LogoLED.h
#ifndef LOGOLED_H
#define LOGOLED_H
#include <FastLED.h>

class LogoLED
{
public:
    LogoLED(uint8_t numLeds, uint8_t dataPin);
    void begin();
    // ... other methods ...
private:
    uint8_t _numLeds;
    uint8_t _dataPin;
    CRGB *_leds;
    bool _isOn;
};
#endif


// LogoLED.cpp
#include "LogoLED.h"

LogoLED::LogoLED(uint8_t numLeds, uint8_t dataPin) : _numLeds(numLeds), _dataPin(dataPin), _isOn(false)
{
    _leds = new CRGB[_numLeds];
}

void LogoLED::begin()
{
    FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, _dataPin, GRB>(_leds, _numLeds);
    off();
}

// ... other methods ...


// main.cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "LogoLED.h"
#define LED_PIN 6
LogoLED logoLED(4, LED_PIN);

void setup()
{
    logoLED.begin();
    // ... more setup code ...
}

void loop()
{
    // ... loop code ...
}

When compiling, I get the following error:
CopyNo instance of overloaded function "CFastLED::addLeds" matches the argument list.
Argument types are: (CRGB *, uint8_t)
Object type is: CFastLED

How can I correctly call the FastLED.addLeds function so that the pin can be set dynamically? I'd like to avoid passing the pin as a template parameter, as I want to maintain the flexibility to change the pin at runtime.
---------- Solution based on Templates as single file --------------
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_LEDS 4
#define LED_PIN 6

template<uint8_t DataPin>
class LogoLED
{
public:
    LogoLED(uint8_t numLeds);
    void begin();
    void on();
    void off();
    void setColor(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b);
    void setBrightness(uint8_t brightness);

private:
    uint8_t _numLeds;
    CRGB *_leds;
    bool _isOn;
};

// Implementierung der LogoLED Methoden

template<uint8_t DataPin>
LogoLED<DataPin>::LogoLED(uint8_t numLeds) : _numLeds(numLeds), _isOn(false)
{
    _leds = new CRGB[_numLeds]; // Dynamisches Array für LEDs erzeugen
}

template<uint8_t DataPin>
void LogoLED<DataPin>::begin()
{
    FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DataPin, GRB>(_leds, _numLeds);
    off(); // Startet mit ausgeschalteten LEDs
}

template<uint8_t DataPin>
void LogoLED<DataPin>::on()
{
    _isOn = true;
    FastLED.show();
}

template<uint8_t DataPin>
void LogoLED<DataPin>::off()
{
    _isOn = false;
    fill_solid(_leds, _numLeds, CRGB::Black); // Alle LEDs ausschalten
    FastLED.show();
}

template<uint8_t DataPin>
void LogoLED<DataPin>::setColor(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b)
{
    fill_solid(_leds, _numLeds, CRGB(r, g, b));
    if (_isOn)
    {
        FastLED.show();
    }
}

template<uint8_t DataPin>
void LogoLED<DataPin>::setBrightness(uint8_t brightness)
{
    FastLED.setBrightness(brightness);
    if (_isOn)
    {
        FastLED.show();
    }
}

// Hauptprogramm

LogoLED<LED_PIN> logoLED(NUMBER_OF_LEDS);

void setup()
{
    logoLED.begin();
    logoLED.setBrightness(10);      
    logoLED.setColor(255, 255, 255);
    logoLED.on();                  
}

void loop()
{
   
}


Seems that _dataPin is not a valid template argument, as it is not known at compile time (not a constexpr).
Try replacing it with a hard-coded number, if it works, think how to represent it in your code. Maybe as a template parameter of your class LogoLED?
Proposed changes:
template<uint8_t DataPin>
class LogoLED
{
public:
    LogoLED(uint8_t numLeds, uint8_t dataPin);
    void begin();
    // ... other methods ...
private:
    uint8_t _numLeds;
    CRGB *_leds;
    bool _isOn;
};

void LogoLED::begin()
{
    FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DataPin, GRB>(_leds, _numLeds);
    off();
}

And for creating the logoLED:
LogoLED logoLED<LED_PIN>(4);


With a hard coded it works. This is also how it is shown in the library description. But I haven't found a working solution to get it running with class member variable. Your codes unfortunately doesn't work
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, 6, GRB>(_leds, _numLeds);

@gear Why do you want to have the LED's pin defined at runtime? Is your hardware such that the LED can be connected to an arbitrary one out of 256 pins by the user? Isn't it rather the case that the LED is soldered to one particular pin?

Sorry my formulation wasn’t correct. I meant that I want to declare the pin by class constructor for easier use. My LED Class doesent need to know my PCB design and can be initialised by the specific project implementation

@gear In which case you should be able to pass it to your class as template parameter, as proposed in the answer, by templating your class: template<uint8_t DataPin> class LogoLED.

@AmirKirsh I have updated the question with the suggested template solution. To be honest, this is beyond my c++ knowledge, but as soon as I try to separate the solution again in .h and .cpp I get a compile error. ChatGPT says: "In C++, template implementations must be included in the header file because the compiler needs the full definition to instantiate the templates during compilation; separating them into a .cpp file leads to linker errors since the implementations are not available where they are used". Can you please help me out?

Alright, I got it working with templates by putting declaration and implementation in the .h file and deleting the .cpp file. But is that a good practice? What do you think?

@gear Yes, this is the way to go. You can implement the template functions inside the class if you want, but it's quite the same.
